# Object safe generic without type erasure

Tags: rust

In the trait `Extendable` below, I'd like to make `app` generic where it currently uses the concrete type `i32`.

At first blush, you'd think to use a generic type but doing so while keeping `Extendable` object safe isn't easy.

```rust
trait Isoextender {
    type Input;
    type Output;
    fn forward(&self, v: Self::Input) -> Self::Output;
    fn backward(&self, v: Self::Output) -> Self::Input;
}

trait Extendable {
    type Item;
    fn app(
        &self,
        v: &dyn Isoextender<Input = Self::Item, Output = i32>,
    ) -> Box<dyn Extendable<Item = i32>>;
}
```

There's a (really neat) type erasure trick ([link](https://www.possiblerust.com/pattern/3-things-to-try-when-you-can-t-make-a-trait-object)) I can use with std::Any but then I'm losing type information.

This is one of those things that **feels** like it should be possible from my understanding of how Rust works but which simply might not be. I do see there's an issue with size. Clearly rust needs to know the size of the associated type `Item`, but I don't see how to solve with with references/pointers in a way that's both object safe and keeps the type information.

Is it the case that:

1. I am missing something and it's actually possible?
2. This is not possible today, but it may become possible in the future?
3. This is not likely to be possible ever?

---

### Update:

So I suppose a part of the issue here is that I feel like the following is a generic function that has only 1 possible implementation. You should only have to compile this once.

```rust
fn pointer_identity<T>(v: &T) -> &T {
    v
}
```

It **feels** like I should be able to put this function into a vtable, but still somehow express that it is generic. There are a whole class of easily identifiable functions that effectively act this way. Interactions between trait objects often act this way. It's all pointers to functions where the types don't matter except to be carried forward.

Comment: better question is why do you want do that.

Comment: The idea is to build some abstractions for WASM where the code size might matter as much as performance. Ideally, without ruining the API too much. But really, I'm just mucking about and hoping I learn things along the way :)

Comment: "Object-safe" essentially means "it's possible to create a virtual function table containing all possible calls we can make to this function". "Generic function" means "this function is actually an infinite class of functions parameterized by some type parameter, and the compiler will monomorphize it". If you try to combine the two, you get "this trait object contains, in finite memory, an infinite number of possible function calls". That's why we can't have generic functions in object-safe traits. The "object-safe" part can't account for all the possibilities of the generic.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yeah, I agree. I'll see if I can conjure a better title. The meat of the issue, however, is that you can have a concrete function that acts generically, this is how old-school C struct-inheritance worked. Hmmm, I'll think about how to reword this. I agree it's confusing.

Comment: @MrkSef That hard to say, but I don't think you will save a lot of by not using generic, anyway, if you have concern like that maybe rust is not the right tool. I have a pretty strong opinion on dyn on Rust, should not even exist, anyway, the thing you ask is impossible, or you need to use dtolnay trick, but again I very strongly against it, this is a VERY complied trick and this will make the code very hard to maintain, and on perf note well dynamic dispatch is slow and memory heavy.

Comment: @MrkSef That makes more sense. I see what you're asking now. And you're right; in theory, Rust could see that `pointer_identity` only uses `T` en passant, not to actually determine the implementation (i.e. never to determine a size or to determine a trait implementation). To my knowledge, Rust doesn't do that kind of analysis right now, and I don't know of any plans to implement it. I tried compiling your `pointer_identity` function right now, and at least in Rust 1.65, it still monomorphizes for each type, even though (as you point out) it could theoretically get away with just one function.

Comment: The compiler needs to know how much stack space to save for `Output` parameter/return type in the trait methods.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman References (Box in this example) always have a known size.

Comment: But what with the methods, `forward()` and `backward()`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman There's a known size for those ossociated types for any given implementation. Those types will be known at compile time. Isoextender is object safe

Comment: But for `app` `Output` will not be known.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, Rust needs to know the size of the associated type Item for Extendable. Which in this case is the same as Output. I don't mind putting them behind a reference (which always has a known size), but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found some document ion that may answer my question.

Currently, the compiler has two concepts surrounding Generic code, only one of which seems to be surfaced in the type system ([link](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/monomorph.html)).

It sounds like this may be possible some day, but not currently expressible with Rust.

### Monomorphization

> The compiler stamps out a different copy of the code of a generic function for each concrete type needed.

### Polymorphization

> In addition to MIR optimizations, rustc attempts to determine when fewer copies of functions are necessary and avoid making those copies - known as "polymorphization".

> As a result of polymorphization, items collected during monomorphization cannot be assumed to be monomorphic.
>
> It is intended that polymorphization be extended to more advanced cases, such as where only the size/alignment of a generic parameter are required.